# Creating a shift cipher in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I want to create an applet where a user can enter a sentance then enter a shift and then the program incrypts the sentance using java. Any help?

im new to java

Comment: The other word that springs to mind is 'homework'

Comment: This is very vague.  Maybe try creating an applet or some code that does the encryption, and then, if you're still having trouble, post a question about a specific problem you're running into.  Preferably with the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, look into how [simple shift ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) work. Second - assuming that your users only can enter common English characters - study the [ASCII character codes](http://www.asciitable.com/). Third, do the math ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading [a tutorial on applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) in java, creating your applet and then reading more about ciphers and writing the encryption part of your program.